# Checking who make pull in project with Git?

Tags: git

Is it possible to check who has made a pull in a project using Git?

The project is hosted on an HTTP server. I can check who made commits, but I can't see who has pulled.

Comment: Can you restate this? I can't really understand what you want. The only thing that tracks users are commits. There's no object called a "pull".

Comment: Where is the project hosted? How is it shared? If it's on a local filesystem, it could be very tricky to establish. If people access it over SSH, then there are authlogs associated with it... HTTP has (optional) logs, too. More information needed.

Comment: Project is on http server. I can check who make commit, but i cant check who make PULL

Comment: And no need to shout. It's "Git".

Comment: Then check your webserver access logs. Git, itself, won't log the pulls, but the HTTP GETs should be logged.

Comment: whatever that hosts the Git repo will be able to track access logs

Comment: ok, thanks. please add new answer

Comment: Aside from the how, I'm curious as to *why*?  Why would you track the pulls?

Comment: I do you do with it..? You can restrict/authenticate the access to git. Why do you concern about pull..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git, itself, does not log pull requests.

Since your project is hosted on a webserver, you should be able to consult your HTTP access logs for the GETs.

Comment: If the files are located at BitBucket, how does the administrator know who has pulled the files?

Comment: @skyclouder I don't think BitBucket offers such a facility.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, from a git perspective, it is not possible.  Git does not maintain any logs.

However, if you are using git in a centralised way, you can see from ssh or http logs if you set that up on the server.

A complication is that its perfectly possible for users to pull from each other rather than from a central server; git is a 'decentralised' version control system.